# My SQL select query with condition using list in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a MySQL table (variable- exchange) with a column name "symbol" and I have a list of string named "listfinalselection". I want to select all rows where the list contains the cell value of column "symbol". But I got a error that there is an error in my SQL syntax. I can't understand that error. Please help. `

```
    Dim mysqlconn As MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=1234;database=Share"
    mysqlconn.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM " & exchange & " WHERE Symbol in (" & String.Concat(",", listfinalselection.Select(Function(i) $"'{i}'").ToArray()) & ");"

    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, mysqlconn)
    Dim datatable As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(datatable)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = datatable
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

    Dim ii As Integer = 0
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Try
            DataGridView1.Rows(ii).Cells(11).Value = listeleventh(listsymbol.IndexOf(DataGridView1.Rows(ii).Cells(3).Value.ToString))
        Catch
        End Try

        ii = ii + 1
    Next

End Sub `
```

Comment: What is the SQL code which produces the error and what is the error?

Comment: You didn't think to list the error you're getting? You might try displaying the result of that String.Concat to see what it is generating. I suspect it's not generating valid sql.

Comment: You should print the variable `sql`, then the issue should become obvious. If you still don't see the error then post the resulting SQL string and the exact error message. The values in the IN clause may need to be quoted too, if the field `Symbol` is of character type...

Comment: That's some pretty nasty injection-hack prone SQL there..

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we can properly and securely query MySQL for a list of values:

```vb
    Dim con = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=1234;database=Share")


    'NOTE WELL: you still have to make sure that exchange contains no SQL!

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & exchange & " WHERE Symbol in (", con)

    For i as Integer = 0 to listfinalselection.Count - 1
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p" & i, listfinalselection(i))
      cmd.CommandText &= "@p" & i & ","
    Next i

    cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.TrimEnd(","c) & ")"
 
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt as New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(dt)
```

Please note, before someone quotes the "Can we stop using AddWithValue already" blog, [it's irrelevant to mysql](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/)